# Designing hierarchy of classes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have this kind of hierarchy in the class design:

[image]

What i wanted to achieve is the most versatile class design that will be flexible enough to cover all the cases.

As you can see in the image, we have cages which are of some material. Now, depending on material type, we can have further categorization inside the cage based on the color (so, in case of plastic cage, we will have 2 compartments where one is red and other is blue) holding animals.

In case of more specific cages (e.g. PLASTIC one), I should be able to call `getBrightestColor()`, which is not present for METAL cage. Case of WOOD-en cage is just more complex PLASTIC one.

This is some code that I have so far, but I don't think neither is OK (added possible problems in comment in code):

```
Cage cg = new Cage(new Specifier(Material.METAL));
cg.addAnimal(new Elephant());
cg.addAnimal(new Dog());
cg.addAnimal(new Cat());
cg.emptyCage();

CageWithSpecifier cg2 = new CageWithSpecifier(new Specifier(Material.PLASTIC)); //need to have different class than Cage, and they are more less same??
cg2.addAnimal(new Specifier(Color.RED), new Dog());
cg2.addAnimal(new Specifier(Color.RED), new Elephant());
cg2.addAnimal(new Specifier(Color.BLUE), new Elephant());
cg2.addAnimal(new Specifier(Color.BLUE), new Cat());
String bc1 = cg2.getBrightestColor();
cg2.emptyCage();

CageWithSpecifier cg3 = new CageWithSpecifier(new Specifier(Material.WOOD));
cg3.addAnimal(new Specifier(Wood.OAK, Color.RED), new Dog());
cg3.addAnimal(new Specifier(Wood.OAK, Color.BLACK), new Elephant());
cg3.addAnimal(new Specifier(Wood.MAPLE, Color.RED), new Dog());

//cg3.getBySpecifier --> ideally should know if it returns leaf or node in hierarchy (without casting?); here we need to cast and whatnot
String bc2 = cg3.getBySpecifier(new Specifier(Wood.OAK)).getBrightestColor();
```

And this one using composite:

```
//using Composite pattern ?
Cage cg3 = new Cage(new Specifier(Material.WOOD));
Cage cg3s1 = new Cage(new Specifier(Wood.OAK)); //cg3s1 is not leaf, but has addAnimal()
Cage cg3s1s1 = new Cage(new Specifier(Color.RED));  //cg3s1s1 is leaf, but will have also addCage()
cg3s1s1.addAnimal(new Dog());
cg3s1.addCage(cg3s1s1);
cg3.addCage(cg3s1);
```

I guess it should be some kind of Composite pattern? Anyone has better suggestions?

**UPDATE** functional requirements

I need to be able to add animal inside cage (eg `METAL`) or inside cage with specifier (eg `PLASTIC+RED`). In case that I have multiple colored inner-cages (eg in case of `PLASTIC` cage or `WOOD+OAK`), I need to be able to `getBrightestColor()`. Cage needs to have `empty()` method that will empty all animals from cage, or `empty(Specifier)` that will empty all animals from inner-cages (in case that I call `empty()` on `PLASTIC` cage, all animals will be emptied from `RED` and `BLUE`). It is possible to have even more levels of specifiers in future (eg GLASS_COLORED__BRIGHT____RED).

Comment: What is `Specifier`?  It appears `Material` should be an attribute of a `Cage`.  Instead of Material.WOOD, have Material.OAK, etc.  Also, it seems Color should be an attribute of Cage, And a cage contains a List of animals. All of these attributes are independent from each other.

Comment: I would say a cage should support a list of animals. But I agree with @AndrewS , Material and Color are attributes of the Cage. Then you could have validation in the constructor if the combination is allowed

Comment: but metal cage has no color or material.OAK. specifier is there to support all future inner-cage classes (e.g. rubber-black-stratchy).

Comment: What is the functionality that you want to get out of this? What you have here is a data model of sorts. If you want to do OO, you have to model the functionality not the data.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam I updated question with minimal set of functional req.

Comment: @bojanv55 That is a technical specification I think, not functional requirements. The only thing that you get "out" of this is the brightest color as far as I can tell. Of animals? If not, why are animals even involved? Why are materials involved? I'm sorry, I still don't understand your scenario.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam my problem is not related to animals at all, but I wanted to present it in a easy-to understand way. This is mostly 1-1 mapping to my current domain that I model. My goal is to hear if somebody else had similar problem and how they solved it (even if only data model - should I have 3 classes, or single one? Should I use composite/something else? etc.).

Comment: I don't know why you separate CageWithSpecifier and Specifier.  For all the world, a Specifier looks like a container holding either additional Specifiers or Animals.   Why not just use ContainerA holds only animals, and ContainerB holds only containers.  Each container possesses a specifier.  Just stack arbitrary structure, and depth-first search for the "brightest" attribute using a visitor parameterized on what type of seach it's performing.

Answer (score 0):

in this implementation, compiler errors are generated if the wrong animal is placed into the wrong compartment.

one should always strive to generate compiler errors if an API is misused. this minimizes runtime errors and bugs.

the [Visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) can be used to perform sub-class-specific operations on subclasses of a super class in cases where only a reference of type superclass is visible.

usage:

```
MetalCage metalCage = new MetalCage();
metalCage.getRegularMetalCompartment().add(new Dog());
metalCage.getRegularMetalCompartment().empty();

PlasticCage plasticCage = new PlasticCage();
plasticCage.getBluePlasticCompartment().add(new Elephant());
plasticCage.getRedPlasticCompartment().add(new Dog());
plasticCage.getRedPlasticCompartment().empty();

WoodCage woodCage = new WoodCage();
woodCage.getRedOakWoodCompartment().add(new Dog());
woodCage.getBlackOakWoodCompartment().add(new Elephant());
woodCage.getRedMapleWoodCompartment().add(new Dog());
woodCage.getRedMapleWoodCompartment().empty();
```

cages:

```
abstract class Cage {
    abstract public Color getBrightestColor();
}

class MetalCage extends Cage {

    private final MetalCompartment regularMetalCompartment = new MetalCompartment();

    public MetalCompartment getRegularMetalCompartment() {
        return regularMetalCompartment;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBrightestColor() {
        return Color.BLACK;
    }
}

class PlasticCage extends Cage {

    private final RedPlasticCompartment redPlasticCompartment = new RedPlasticCompartment();
    private final BluePlasticCompartment bluePlasticCompartment = new BluePlasticCompartment();

    public BluePlasticCompartment getBluePlasticCompartment() {
        return bluePlasticCompartment;
    }

    public RedPlasticCompartment getRedPlasticCompartment() {
        return redPlasticCompartment;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBrightestColor() {
        return Color.RED;
    }
}

class WoodCage extends Cage {

    private final RedOakWoodCompartment redOakWoodCompartment = new RedOakWoodCompartment();
    private final BlackOakWoodCompartment blackOakWoodCompartment = new BlackOakWoodCompartment();
    private final RedMapleWoodCompartment redMapleWoodCompartment = new RedMapleWoodCompartment();

    public RedOakWoodCompartment getRedOakWoodCompartment() {
        return redOakWoodCompartment;
    }

    public BlackOakWoodCompartment getBlackOakWoodCompartment() {
        return blackOakWoodCompartment;
    }

    public RedMapleWoodCompartment getRedMapleWoodCompartment() {
        return redMapleWoodCompartment;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBrightestColor() {
        return Color.RED;
    }
}
```

compartments:

```
abstract class Compartment<Prisoner> {
    private final List<Prisoner> prisoners = new ArrayList<Prisoner>();

    public List<Prisoner> getPrisoners() {
        return prisoners;
    }

    public void add(Prisoner prisoner) {
        prisoners.add(prisoner);
    }

    public void empty() {
        prisoners.clear();
    }
}

class MetalCompartment extends Compartment<MetalCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}

class RedPlasticCompartment extends Compartment<RedPlasticCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}

class BluePlasticCompartment extends Compartment<BluePlasticCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}

class RedOakWoodCompartment extends Compartment<RedOakWoodCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}

class BlackOakWoodCompartment extends Compartment<BlackOakWoodCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}

class RedMapleWoodCompartment extends Compartment<RedMapleWoodCompartment.Prisoner> {
    interface Prisoner {
    }
}
```

animals:

```
class Dog implements RedMapleWoodCompartment.Prisoner, RedOakWoodCompartment.Prisoner, MetalCompartment.Prisoner, RedPlasticCompartment.Prisoner {
}

class Elephant implements BlackOakWoodCompartment.Prisoner, MetalCompartment.Prisoner, BluePlasticCompartment.Prisoner, RedPlasticCompartment.Prisoner {
}

class Cat implements MetalCompartment.Prisoner, BluePlasticCompartment.Prisoner {
}
```

Comment: thanks for effort, but this does not seem as very versitle design. You have class explosion here. if there is tomorrow new container type, i would need to make new class with all the methods, and logic is actually same between all the clases.

Comment: just as a note to my question - logic between all classes can be shared. only this data model varies (hierarchy - how deep is which animal in classes)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use composite here.** Though I am not showing the implementation of it, I thought of something like this which might give you some ideas on how to tackle this problem. Brain food

*Enums used:*

```
enum Property {
OAK, MAPLE
}

enum Color {
BLUE, RED, BLACK
}

enum Material {
METAL, PLASTIC, WOOD
}
```

*Cage, Compartment and exemplary Animal classes*

```
class Cage {
Material material;
HashSet<Compartment> compartments;
HashMap<Property, HashSet> compartmentsByProperty;

Cage(Material material) throws NoSuchMaterialException {
    switch (material) {
        case METAL: // for no Properties and single compartment
            compartments = new HashSet<>();
            compartments.add(new Compartment());
            break;
        case PLASTIC: // for no Properties and multiple compartments
            compartments = new HashSet<>();
            compartments.add(new Compartment(Color.BLUE));
            compartments.add(new Compartment(Color.RED));
            break;
        case WOOD: // for multiple Properties and multiple compartments for each
            compartmentsByProperty = new HashMap<>();
            HashSet<Compartment> oakCompartments = new HashSet<>();
            oakCompartments.add(new Compartment(Color.BLACK));
            oakCompartments.add(new Compartment(Color.RED));
            compartmentsByProperty.put(Property.OAK, oakCompartments);
            HashSet<Compartment> mapleCompartments = new HashSet<>();
            oakCompartments.add(new Compartment(Color.RED));
            compartmentsByProperty.put(Property.MAPLE, mapleCompartments);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NoSuchMaterialException();
    }
}

void empty() {
    // clear stuff
}
}

class Compartment {
private Color color;
private ArrayList compartment;

Compartment() {
    compartment = new ArrayList<Animal>();
}

Compartment(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
    compartment = new ArrayList<Animal>();
}

public void clear() {
    compartment.clear();
}
}

class Elephant extends Animal {}
```

And one comment though, please try to make you OOP simple and easy to understand since that is how it supposed to be done. It relates to how you are naming variables, classes and methods too! If you feel like you have to name your variables like `cg3s1s1`, or have `CageWithSpecifier` types, there is most likely something wrong with the idea in the first place.